# GTK# sctructure of application

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I am newbie in desktop application programs and  I want to create an applications which will use only 1 window for all things. First of all I create a simple LOGIN form with "Login" button and 2 text fields. When user successfully logins window changes it's form. I pinned a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG9RL.jpg) of the, lets say, MAIN form, where user can switch between "screens" (I don't know how to properly name it) by clicking 1..4 buttons at the right. And we have the top panel with profile photo and nickname which persist all the time program still in the MAIN form.

So, the main question is: HOW should I do it? Which widgets I should use and how does dynamic content in GTK+ (and others, like Qt etc.) should be implemented? So I want answers, links to topics which covers this situation, guides and lessons. Anything will help.

I read a lot of documentation but it seems that I can't find proper information just because I don't know how to formulate my problem for search query.

Thank you, I hope I'll find some help.

P.S. I am gonna use C# and GTK# for this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html). This will enable you to have multiple *widget layouts* in a single window and provides you with an easy way to change which widgets are shown. GtkStack is commonly used with [StackSwitcher](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStackSwitcher.html). However normal buttons will work just as well. Can I also suggest you use [Glade](https://developer.gnome.org/glade/stable/) to lay out your widgets? This will give you a presentation of how your widgets sets will look.

Edit: GtkStack does not appear to be available for Gtk#.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a very interesting container. It looks like it will help somehow.
But, unfortunately, GTK# lacks of this feature as I see (correct me if I am wrong), so I will keep listen to answers.
About Glade: yes, I used it. Also I have some designer (maybe even glade)  inbuilt in my Xamarin Studio and Monodevelop, where I have WYSIWYG workflow with widgets.

Comment: Disclaimer: I use Python. I thought all Gtk widgets are available under all programming languages. Hitting Google does not come up with GtkStack for C# though. Which makes me curious, don't you use GObject Introspection?

Comment: So what about creating new widget inside panel every time user hits the button? The panel will be at center of window. Is it a good idea?

Comment: It can be done by removing the widget from its parent container and adding a new child widget, It is a bit more tricky than GtkStack. One other thing some programmers have done is to add all widgets and then set some visible and set some invisible.

Comment: In this case all the widgets will be above each other (logically) and when the button is pressed one group of widgets will set active. Ok, this seems legit. Thanks

Comment: Hey! Sorry for bother you. I tried to use glade and custom css, but I have a problem.
I can add custom css file in my glade project and I will have custom elements when I am running preview inside glade. But when I export it in XML and create GtkBuilder, I have no custom CSS styling nor in XML, nor in actual app.
So, the new question is, how do I add my css styles to glade XML file to use it with builder?
My contacts: t.me/interpol_kun

Comment: CSS rendering does not apply to this post. Please start a new question to keep answers related to the question. I am not sure what you mean by *My contacts: t.me/interpol_kun*. If your app is open source, do you have a project on GitHub or SourceForge I can look at? CSS is something that has interested me.

Comment: This is the Telegram link to my profile. It's a messenger and I gave you an url. I have no remote repository, because I have no app. I have finished design and concept. The bottleneck is understanding of GTK. And I just suggesting you to go there (Telegram) just because I have lots of questions and I don't want to start a new one for each one.

Comment: Telegram will not work for me (various reasons). I feel you should open a new question on SO every time. These will get the same amount attention that any other correspondence does (email / messenging) and other people can benefit too :) . I check SO every day or so for Gtk questions.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to create various boxes (**Gtk.VBox** or **Gtk.HBox**), and hide/show them as you need to. I did not know about Gtk.Stack, but I bet it uses the same principle, maybe with some optimization.

```
class UniqueWindowView: Gtk.Window
{
    void Build()
    {
        var vbMainBox = new Gtk.VBox();

        this.vbLoginPage = this.BuildLoginPage();
        this.vbNotebook = this.BuildNotebook();

        vbMainBox.PackStart( this.vbLoginPage, true, true, 100 );
        vbMainBox.PackStart( this.vbNotebook, true, true, 5 );
        vbMainBox.Show();

        this.Add( vbMainBox );
        this.SetSizeRequest( 600, 400 );
        this.Show();
    }

    // ...

    public Gtk.VBox vbLoginPage {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Gtk.VBox vbNotebook {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Gtk.Notebook nbNotebook {
        get; private set;
    }

    public Gtk.Button btLogin {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

Once you have this scheme running, you have to prepare to show or hide the appropriate boxes.

```
class UniqueWindowCtrl
{
    public UniqueWindowCtrl()
    {
        this.view = new UniqueWindowView();
        this.view.DeleteEvent += (o, args) => this.Quit();
        this.view.btLogin.Clicked += (sender, e) => this.ShowNotebook();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.ShowLogin();
    }

    public void ShowLogin()
    {
        this.view.vbLoginPage.Show();
        this.view.nbNotebook.Hide();
    }

    public void ShowNotebook()
    {
        this.view.vbLoginPage.Hide();
        this.view.nbNotebook.Show();
    }

    void Quit()
    {
        this.view.Hide();
        Gtk.Application.Quit();
    }

    UniqueWindowView view;
}
```

You can find the whole source code for a [unique window in GTK# here](https://github.com/Baltasarq/GtkUniqueWindowDemo).
Hope this helps.